# Building native iOS app Sencha 2 "Bundle Seed ID is missing from config file"

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I dont understand this error message, when I run the following command I get:

```
C:\projectsGit\mybipper\portal\bk-servlets\src\main\webapp\parentapp>sencha package build ../nativeBuild/packager.json
[INFO] The application was successfully packaged
Bundle Seed ID is missing from config file
Failed to package application
```

My packager.json is :

```
{
    "applicationName":"MobileKids",
    "applicationId":"TC3BU5LD52.com.bipper.mobilekids",
    "versionString":"1.1",
    "iconName":"icon.png",
    "inputPath":".",
    "outputPath":"../build",
    "configuration":"Debug",
    "platform":"iOS",
    "deviceType":"Universal",
    "certificatePath":"Certificate_key.p12",
    "certificateAlias":"iPhone Developer: Thomas Vervik (TC3BU5LD52)",
    "sdkPath":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk",
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "landscapeLeft",
        "landscapeRight",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in ST2: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192946-2.0.1RC-Native-build-seem-to-be-broken&s=5fd0b1665305e83413dea48c9b4ee510

Are you running the latest version? Also, there are some workaround provided in the above post.

Comment: Hi Jerrery!

I found your link on Google later, and added that property, and then it worked! I use SDK tools to Beta3, so strange that it wasnt working there